# Replace comma with space in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Replace comma with space using a shell script

Given the following input:

```
Test,10.10.10.10,"80,22,3306",connect
```

I need to get below output using a `bash` script

```
Test 10.10.10.10 "80,22,3306" connect
```

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: because you have commas inside one of the fields `"80,22,3306"`, you're better off using a csv parser for some programming language (e.g. python) and then emitting the fields with the delimiter you actually want.

Answer (score 2):

If you have gawk, you can use FPAT (field pattern), setting it to a regular expression.

```
awk -v FPAT='([^,]+)|(\"[^"]+\")' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { printf "%s ",$i } }' <<< "Test,10.10.10.10,\"80,22,3306\",connect"
```

We set FPAT to separate the text based on anything that is not a comma and also data enclosed in quotation marks as as well as anything that is not a quotation mark. We then print all the fields with a spaces in between.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can read your input from the file, this works

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while read -r line;do
declare -a begin=$(echo $line | awk -F'"' '{print $1}' | tr "," " " )
declare -a end=$(echo $line |awk -F'"' '{print $3}' | tr "," " " )
declare -a middle=$(echo $line | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' )

echo "${begin[@]} \"${middle[@]}\" ${end[@]}"
done < connect_file
```

Edit: I see,that you want to keep the commas between port numbers. I have edited the script.

Answer (score 0):

Considering if your Input_file is same as shown sample then following sed may help you in same too.

```
sed 's/\(.[^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\(".*"\),\(.*\)/\1 \2 \3 \4/g'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Test,10.10.10.10,\"80,22,3306\",connect|awk '{sub(/,/," ")gsub(/,"80,22,3306",/," \4280,22,3306\42 ")}1'

Test 10.10.10.10 "80,22,3306" connect
```

Comment: It is unlikely that the OP wants this only to work for the single exact input given.